# the import android could not be resolved

Tags: android

I opened a project that I had not opened in a while in Eclipse today. I was unable to compile due to some (inexplicable) errors.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.content.Intent;
```

produces the following error:

> the import android could not be resolved

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: create new project and see what happen it run or not?

Answer (score 43):

First try clean / build your project.

If the problem persists. Right click on the project -> go to properties -> go to android -> select the android version and that should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! In my case the problem was that merging projects I replaced my project.properties field with a target android version I didn't have. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 9):

Try one of these:

- ‘Clean’ Your Eclipse Project: Go to Project > Clean in Eclipse [This seems to work for me]
- Refresh your project folder (right click on your project > refresh)
  Re-build your project
- Clean your builds (If using Ant or Maven – clean your builds)
  Recreate your project in Eclipse
- ‘Switch’ Workspace – then Switch back (Eg Change to Debug, then switch back to Java)
- ‘Switch’ Workspace – then Switch back (Eg Change to Debug, then switch back to Java)
- Remove and re-add your JRE:

  1. Right Click on your project > properties
  2. Click on the Libraries tab
  3. Click on the JRE
  4. Click remove, then OK
  5. Repeat 1-3 again, but add the JRE again

Comment: switching workspace is what did it for me. A1++ would switch again

Answer (score 4):

Well, I also ran into that problem when I imported an existing Android project from a friend into my workspace. I found that I was missing JRE library but also **Android** library (Android Classpath Container library). You can add it like this:

1. Right Click on your project > properties
2. Click on the Libraries tab
3. Click on "Add Library.." button on the right
4. Add Android Classpath Container library

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is an updated answer for if you're using Android Studio. You may run into this problem due to how it caches.

In the event that you get this error with any package it's a good idea to go to **File** -> **Invalidate Cache/Restart** and select to drop the cache.

This can also fix issues that sometimes might persist between reinstalls due to the fact that upon uninstall Android Studio does not delete the cache.

Comment: can't delete comment.

Comment: Did a complete system restart (Mac OS), launched Android studio then invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio to solve the issue.

A full day wasted! :(

Answer (score 1):

Also Make sure that, the current application and imported libraries/applications are having the same android API versions... (14, 15, 17, etc)... The mismatch of API version also will cause the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I Need to go to Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export

After checking the Android 4.0 Library ( may be different version in your case) it started working

Answer (score 0):

So none of the other solutions worked for me but I found another way that worked for me.

Right click on the project -> go to properties ->Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs

YOUR_DRIVE\android-sdks\platforms\android-??

add android.jar file