# fail import external libraries in Android Studio

Tags: android

i'm working on my (multidex) android application and it seems the 1.1.0 AS update has broken my project structure.
I'm using API Level 19 w. JDK 1.7.0_75 and build tools 21.1.2.

problem is that AS cannot resolve any of my external libraries.
The libs seems to be imported correctly, they're listed in the project windows under external libraries, my module references them and gradle contains:

```
dependencies {
    //does not work
    provided 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

Within a class import cannot be resolved but "intellisense" is able to detect and autocomplete the namespace.

[image]

weird thing is rebuilding and debugging the application works except that adb stops to work after the apk has been installed and launched on the device. It pops up the "Waiting for debugger" window but nothing happens and logcats error output is
"Starting window AppWindowToken{} timed out".

Comment: Try rebooting your phone and the PC if you haven't, it seems something may have gotten out of sync.

Comment: @MeetTitan thanks for your answer but yes already tried that... including a reinstall of android studio + sdks + jdk. exactly the same problem after reconfiguring all of it.

Comment: A question, have you tried to gradle sync while you are connected to a VPN? if not please try this. google site is closed to IP of some countries like Iran so you should use VPN.

Comment: @ErfanMowlaei hmm, i'm in germany, is it this far that we're blacklisted now?:D

Comment: Can you try *File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart* and drop all caches?

Comment: @user1740750 haha, I didn't know your location so I just guessed :D

Comment: @PaulThompson omg THAT is it! and I started with this post <a href>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487497/the-import-android-could-not-be-resolved</a> which didn't helped and started rreinstalling sdks, jdks and rebooting for hours...maybe you want to add this as a solution?thank you much u saved my day.

Comment: Wicked :D I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often this comes as Android Studio caches a bunch of information that persists between installs. As soon as you're getting an issue it's a good idea to go to *File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart* and drop the cache.

It will be a bit slow when it restarts but can often solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Complete system restart followed by the above mentioned steps solved the issue.