# java.lang.invoke cannot resolve import android?

Tags: java, android

I adding this code my app project and after compile error show cannot resolve import, how can i use this code android API 9,

```
import java.lang.invoke.ConstantCallSite;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class BootstrapMethod{

    public static Object bootstrap(MethodHandles.Lookup lookup, String callerName, MethodType callerType,
            int originalOpcode, String originalClassName, String originalMethodName, String originalMethodSignature) {

        MethodHandle mh = null;
        try {
            // variables initialization
            Class clazz = Class.forName(originalClassName);
            ClassLoader currentClassLoader = BootstrapMethod.class.getClassLoader();
            MethodType originalMethodType = MethodType.fromMethodDescriptorString(originalMethodSignature,
                    currentClassLoader);
            // lookup method handle
            switch (originalOpcode) {
            case 0xB8: // invokestatic opcode
                mh = lookup.findStatic(clazz, originalMethodName, originalMethodType);
                break;
            case 0xB6: // invokevirtual opcode
            case 0xB9: // invokeinterface opcode
                mh = lookup.findVirtual(clazz, originalMethodName, originalMethodType);
                break;
            default:
                throw new BootstrapMethodError();
            }
            mh = mh.asType(callerType);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new BootstrapMethodError();
        }
        return new ConstantCallSite(mh);
    }
}
```

any other library and solution to solve and use this code android API 9?

Comment: working android studio or ecllipse?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487497/the-import-android-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: Android studio.

Comment: update your sdk tools

Comment: update, not solve.

Comment: Same issue occurs for me. Do you know a way to fix this issue? @Hide